# Damage, or normal wear and tear on a rental?

Tags: rental-property, residential-lease

Our landlord is claiming damage on some cabinet doors, and wants to completely replace them. We're trying to figure out if we can challenge him on it.

Note that the pictures shown here still showed the childproof locks. These were later removed cleanly except for one which removed a bit of finish. Anyway, the landlord isn't complaining about those spots, but about the scuffs you can see in these images—specially the ones in the curved bathroom vanity doors.

[image: Vanity doors]

[image: Kitchen cabinet doors]

Comment: Let us know what jurisdiction and we can try to find some law that would help define normal wear and tear. However, I think you're okay and that is normal wear and tear.

Comment: It's New York City

Comment: Some scuffing is to be expected. Even if it weren't, you'd only be liable to repair, not replace, this kind of "damage". A little oil, polish or a dab of stain (or even Sharpie) would probably fix that right up.